# How to test that a sample of a discrete random variable is representative?

Tags: references, sample, representative

I am given a discrete random variable and several large samples from it. The methods how the samples are obtained are not truly random samples but are reasonable approximations to a random sample.

An analogy would be you want to study all pupils in a school discrict and your sample contains all students whose last name starts with an A. Not truly random but probably quite close to it.

The task is to measure how close to a truly random and representative sample the given samples are and to decide which method does best in delivering a representative sample of the given random variable.

Some online searching gave me the [Cramer-von Mises test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion) or the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) but both of these are more designed for continuous random variables although they can be adapted to the discrete case. I'm mostly looking for a good reference, possibly at a textbook level on what methods there are for this kind of problem and what the advantages and disadvantages are.

Comment: Re "probably quite close to it:" that's doubtful, because initial letters of names will be (strongly) associated with ethnicity, language, and culture; so if you are interested in any other characteristic that might conceivably be linked with that factor, your sample could be terribly biased.  Getting to your question, what information do you propose working with?  If you are sampling, presumably you don't know the entire population, so what are you going to compare your sample to and on what basis?

Comment: @whuber Your comment on association with ethnicity etc is excellent, I was pondering whether to include something like that in my analogy. The question is how big this bias is? Of course this depends on the characteristic being studied but I would like to get some explicit numeric estimates for that. I do have individual data in the sample but only aggregate data on the entire population.